# How to dynamically create a class in Python with an initializer

Tags: python

Here is some code to start with:

```
def objectify(name, fields):
    """ Create a new object including the __init__() method. """
    def __init__(self, *argv):
        for name, val in zip(var_names, argv):
            setattr(self, name, val)

    # The following line of code is currently limited to a single dynamic class.
    # We would like to extend it to allow creating multiple classes
    # and each class should remember it's own fields.
    __init__.var_names = fields

    result = type(name, (object,), dict(__init__=__init__))
```

The challenge here is to find a way to make unique copies of the `__init__()` method of each class which has a static list of its variable names.

Plan B:
We can do this using `eval()` to run code that a function generates. But `eval()` is to be avoided wherever possible. The challenge here is to do this without `eval()`.

EDIT: While writing up the question I came up with a solution. (See below.) Maybe this will help someone.

EDIT2: I would use this function to create something like a `namedtuple()`, except that they are mutable.

```
Point = objectify('point', ['x', 'y'])
a = Point(1, 2)
b = Point(2, 3)
print a.__dict__
print b.__dict__
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention anything about the usage of fields later on. If you only need them in `__init__`, you don't need to save them at all:

```
def objectify(name, fields):
    """ Create a new object including the __init__() method. """
    fields = fields[:]
    def __init__(self, *argv):
        for name, val in zip(fields, argv):
            setattr(self, name, val)

    result = type(name, (object,), dict(__init__=__init__))
    return result
```

Otherwise, you should look at metaclasses - that's exactly the usecase for them.

Updated: making a copy of `fields` ensures that changing the list in the caller will not affect the stored one. The values can still change... left as an exercise to the reader to verify everything is a `str`.

Comment: I added 'EDIT2' to explain how you would use this function; sort of like a mutable `namedtuple()`.

Comment: That works just fine my solution. No need for extra storage.

Comment: I verified your solution, you are correct! I am curious about why this works.

Comment: @ChaimG Bi Rico explained above, but tagged the wrong person.

Comment: @viraptor @ChaimG I tried, but I didn't do a very good job, so let me try again :). This is called a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). The basic idea is that `__init__` is created dynamically every time `objectify` is called. Each `__init__` function is created with reference to the value of `fields` in it's local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
def objectify(obj_name, fields):
    """ Create a new object including the __init__() method. """

    def __init__(self, *argv):
        """ Generic initializer for dynamically created classes. """
        fields = objectify.fields[self.__class__.__name__]
        for field, val in zip(fields, argv):
            setattr(self, field, val)

    result = type(obj_name, (object,), dict())
    result.__init__ = __init__

    # Save the list of fields in a static dictionary that is retrieved by class name.
    objectify.fields[obj_name] = fields

    return result

objectify.fields = {}           # A static local variable.
```